# Determine $X$ up to homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a non-empty topological space. Assume that every function $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Determine $X$ up to homeomorphism, assuming that $X$ is countable.

My try: If $X$ is infinite, then the choices would be $\mathbb{Z}$, or $\mathbb{Q}$ with discrete topology. Or $X$ is finite. Would it be correct way to think of?

Comment: Z and Q with the discrete topology are the same (homeomorphic). If  a countable space did not have the discrete topology, try to construct $f$ that is not continuous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $A \subset X$ let $f(x)=1$ for $x \in A$ and $0$ for $x \notin A$. Continuity of $f$ shows that $A$ is open. Thus $X$ has discrete topology. Hence it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb N$ with discrete topology if it is infinite and to $\{1,2,...,N\}$ with discrete topology if it has cardinality $N$.